# Make a UIButton open .mobileconfig

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How do I make a UIButton open a .mobileconfig file? I've tried UIWebView but it's not working, and I'd rather not use UIWebView.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.mobileconfigue can not be opened by any app except mail and safari.